# How to transform the es6 import to AMD require

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, frontend

I'm writing es6 import like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append($('<p>hello es6 module</p>'));
});
```

Then I want to run it in the browser,so I just use babel to transform it to es5 file, it's no doubt that babel will transform it to CommonJS file, so I install the babel plugin 'transform-es2015-modules-amd', then I try again, but this time,babel transform my es6 code to this kind of thing:

```
define(['jquery'], function (_jquery) {.........});
```

But I just want to transform it to this kind of thing:

```
require(['jquery'],function($){......});
```

So how I can make this dream come true, I would appreciate it if you can give me any suggestions, thanks a lot!

Comment: You tagged typescript. What's the typescript target? Es5? Module type amd?

Comment: This is ecmascript 2015 grammer, and I want to transform the 'import' to AMD standard code require([''],fuction(){});

Comment: Sure. If you are using typescript, you dont need babel. TS will transpire to es5 (require) and also output amd module syntax

Comment: Aha, yes, but I'm just using es6  raw grammar, It seems that I can't solve this problem by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a build script for the browser integration. gulp is ver good for that
like this example. using browserify for the browser integration. will work with require and import

// gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
gulp.task('build', function () {
  browserify({
    entries: 'index.js',
    extensions: ['.js'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

in your index.js use the source you would like and use the bundle.js output within your browser.

- Browserify traversed your dependency tree, starting with  index.js
- Transpiled source files to ES5
- Bundled them all together into one file
- Sent it to the dist  directory

if you dont want to bundle everything like vendorlibs jquery and so on there are some configuration options for browserify. they allowing you to use require on external libs ext for browserify i use is browserify-global-shim.

**conclusion:**

```
npm install --save-dev browserify babelify
```

*optional packages*

```
browserify-global-shim
```

gulp is not required but helps alot with build

```
gulp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this must can help me, I can't thank you more, and I think I need to spend some time to learn how to use the browserify and babelify package of gulp, thank you for your help, and welcome to China and have a visit to my hometown!